# PDF(probability density function) question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Q: The yearly inflation rate in the country follow the follows probability density function:

$ f(x)  =  \frac{c}{x^{3}} $ for  $ > 1$; otherwise $0$

Where c is a constant.

a) Find the value of $c$.

b) Find an approximate probability that exactly $1$ out of $5$ coming years have yearly inflation rate greater than $20$. (Hint: $p$ is small)

c) Find cumulative distribution function of $x$.

Now I found the value of $c$ using integration. $c = 2$

Part (c) is easy as well. The CDF I found is $-\frac{1}{x^{2}} + 1$

But I don't understand part (b). Can someone please give a hint?

Edit: Should I do it like $P(X>20) = 1 - P(X\leq 20)? $

$$P(X\leq 20) = \int_{1}^{20} \frac{2}{x^3} \,dx $$

Comment: That is the probability that in a given year the inflation rate is greater than 20. You need the other four years to have an inflation rate of at most 20.

Comment: ${5 \choose 1} P(X \gt 20) \cdot (P(X \lt 20))^4$